# How to show a detail table as a popup button for each master record

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I would like to have a table with a popup window in each row taking me to details view of that row.

When I add the detail table inside the popup tag as a child of of the inner dialog windows, I get the below error message.

"Element af:table in not allowed inside af:table."

Please let me know how I can show a details table in a popup tag as using link in each row.

Your help is much appreciate it.

Mehdi

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered in this question in this thread https://community.oracle.com/message/14205682#14205682

Timo